# Pixel Manipulation in SDL2.0

Tags: c, sdl-2

I can not display pixels in SDL 2.0.

```
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

void end( SDL_Window *Window, SDL_Surface *Surface);
void drawPixel( SDL_Surface *Surface, int x, int y);
void main(){
    Uint32 start;
    const int FPS = 60;
    bool running = true;
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Window *main_window = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *main_screen = NULL;
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    main_window =  SDL_CreateWindow("Pixel", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,800,600,
                        SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

    main_screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface ( main_window );
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( main_window );

    //printf("%d\n",main_screen->pixels);
    SDL_FillRect( main_screen, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(main_screen->format, 255, 255, 255));
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( main_window );
    for(int i = 0; i <= 3000; i++ ){
        drawPixel( main_screen, i, 0);
        //break;
    }
   // SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( main_window );

    while( running ) {
      //  start = SDL_GetTicks();
        while ( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) ){
            switch( event.type ){
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    running = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    end( main_window, main_screen);

}

void end(SDL_Window *Window, SDL_Surface *Surface){
    SDL_FreeSurface( Surface );
    SDL_DestroyWindow( Window );
}

void drawPixel(SDL_Surface *Surface, int x, int y){
    Uint8 *pixel_array = (Uint8 *) Surface->pixels;
    Uint8 *pixel = pixel_array + Surface->pitch * y + x;
    *pixel = SDL_MapRGB(Surface->format, 0, 0, 0 );
}`
```

I tried to locate pixel position and try to color the pixel black while background color white, but it does not print anything.
Although I tried to create a line in case i am not unable to see the pixel, but it turned out to be not working. I see only white screen.

Comment: So what do you see instead? White screen, black screen, blue screen, dancing piglets?

Comment: I see all White Screen

Comment: You draw a white pixel on white background and see a white screen. How do you know that the pixel was not drawn?

Comment: i draw a black pixel on white screen.

Comment: "try to color the pixel white" Would you like to rephrase your question?

Comment: that was my mistake, I am sorry

Comment: How did you come up with the code? Can you start from a working tutorial (somethign like a SDL2 hello world) and make something work? Then start to increment towards your goal?

Comment: Did you notice the question listed on the side under "Related"? Is any of them helpful?

Comment: I started from scratch only , and stucked here.

Comment: Tutorial or other questions seem a wise path then.

Comment: First you update the window, then you draw pixels. Try the other way around.

Comment: Your `drawPixel` assumes pixel occupies single byte. That may be (check surface format), but very unlikely. For most formats pixels stored in `Uint32`.